# how to Display the Image From Database and Display In View in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image

Hi All  i have a FileUpload Control where users can upload Images and Doc files and i am saving the Url of the Path in My Database
now when i am retrieving the data from database i want to check wether the file is .doc or image if it is Doc it will open the file my problem is how do i do it for Image how can i check wether its a image And i have to show the image in a image control never worked on image controls in MVC3

here is my Controller Code

```
       public ActionResult ViewAttachments(string AttachmentName)
    {
        try
        {
            AttachmentName = Session["AttachmentUrl"].ToString();
            var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(" "+ AttachmentName+" "));
            return File(fs, "application/doc", AttachmentName);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "Couldn't find " + AttachmentName);
        }
    }
```

i am using an aspx page here What html i have to use and what is the Code i have to change here any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is a simple check on the extension and either return the FILE result as you are doing or a partial view which holds a simple image control.

To expand on your code you could do something like this:

```
public ActionResult ViewAttachments(string AttachmentName)
    {
        try
        {
            AttachmentName = Session["AttachmentUrl"].ToString();
            var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(" " + AttachmentName + " "));
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(fs.Name);

            switch (ext)
            {
                case "doc":
                    return File(fs, "application/doc", AttachmentName);
                case "jpg":
                case "jpeg":
                case "png":
                    return PartialView("_imgControl", "http://www.mysite.com/downloads/" + AttachmentName + ext); 
            }                
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "Couldn't find " + AttachmentName);
        }
    }
```

Then on your partial view you could just return the model object (in this case the url of the image path on your site) to a standard html image control.